# how can i join 3 tables in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables tags,tag_type,user_alert
table structure is as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE  `tags` (
`tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `tagtype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag_types` (
`tagtype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tagtype_name_en` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `tagtype_name_fr` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `display_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_color` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;


  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_alert` (
`user_alert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_removed` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT 'no',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

I have created query, but it is not working for me.

```
select t.tag_name,t.tag_id,ty.tag_color,ty.tagtype_name_en as tagtype_name from tags as t INNER JOIN tag_types as ty ON t.tagtype_id=ty.tagtype_id INNER JOIN user_alert as ua ON ua.tag_id != t.tag_id  where t.tagtype_id='5' and ua.user_id != '14'
```

I want to make query such that
I am passing tagtype_id and user_id

when I pass tagtype_id I can get all tag which belongs to that tagtyped_id and don not want to select tags in which user has subscribed.

but I am not able to do it.I know the answer will be simple but don't know how to do it.can anybody please help me?

Comment: can you reformat your question?

Comment: @kiran gadhvi    You don't have a "tagtype_name_en" Field in your "tag_types" Table, now do you?

Comment: Please provide full table structure, and if possible also provide some data too, SQLFiddle will be best

Comment: @Poiz i didn't mention some fields but it's there in table.

Answer (score 0):

In JOIN, you must use "=" and dont use "!=".
your condition must apply in where statement NOT in join.

Comment: She wasn't using "!=" in the join clause but on the where clause: **WHERE t.tagtype_id='5' AND ua.user_id != '14'";**

Comment: in this segment INNER JOIN user_alert as ua ON ua.tag_id != t.tag_id

Comment: Perfect Observation, mate... You are Right.... 1 Up for you ;-) just spotted it now....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Table definition you supplied here is accurate; the problem is that you don't have a tagtype_name_en Field in your "tag_types" table and you are trying to access it while it doesn't exist.

```
       // YOUR TABLE DEFINITION/COLUMNS:::
        TABLE 1 - tags:
        tag_id
        tag_name
        tagtype_id


        TABLE 2 - tag_types
        tagtype_id
        tag_color  
        tagtype_name_en

        TABLE 3 - user_alert
        tag_id
        user_id
```

**UPDATE: ADDED GROUP BY CLAUSE**

```
        $sql = "SELECT
            t.tag_name, t.tag_id,
            ty.tag_color,ty.tagtype_name_en AS tagtype_name
            FROM tags AS t
            LEFT JOIN tag_types AS ty ON t.tagtype_id=ty.tagtype_id
            LEFT JOIN user_alert AS ua ON ua.tag_id!=t.tag_id
            GROUP BY t.tag_id
            WHERE t.tagtype_id='5' AND ua.user_id != '14'";
```

Comment: @kiran gadhvi  I updated it... However, the idea here is to try using the GROUP BY Clause. You may just revise your own Query and try adding the GROUP BY Clause.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try with this **<>** not equal to operator  instead of **!=**

```
SELECT * FROM `tags` AS `t` INNER JOIN `tag_types` AS `ty` ON t.tagtype_id = ty.tagtype_id INNER JOIN `user_alert` AS `ua` ON ua.tag_id <> t.tag_id WHERE t.tagtype_id = '5' AND ua.user_id <> '14'
```

**UPDATED**

Try this  **"LEFT JOIN"**

```
 SELECT * FROM `tags` AS `t` INNER JOIN `tag_types` AS `ty` ON t.tagtype_id = ty.tagtype_id LEFT JOIN `user_alert` AS `ua` ON ua.tag_id = t.tag_id WHERE t.tagtype_id = '5' AND ua.user_id <> '14' AND ua.tag_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for (untested as i don't have this DB)

```
select t.tag_name,
       t.tag_id,
       ty.tag_color,
       ty.tagtype_name_en as tagtype_name
  from tags as t
 INNER JOIN user_alert as ua
    ON ua.tag_id <> t.tag_id
 INNER JOIN tag_types as ty
    ON ua.tag_id = ty.tagtype_id
 where t.tagtype_id = '5'
   and ua.user_id <> '14
```

Comment: Your SQL is clean regardless of if you tested it or not, however; her Table Definition makes no mention of the Column: **tagtype_name_en** as you can also see from the **Fields in her 2nd Table: tag_types**... unless she forgot to tell us about it...

Comment: @Poiz i just added that field but actually that's not the actual error.

Comment: @kirangadhvi    Ah, OK... Excuse me then ;-) I just thought it was an Error or something....

Comment: @Poiz that's what i am saying error is that query is not proper. i am not getting expected output.

Comment: @kirangadhvi    Did you recognize this part of the Query: **INNER JOIN ON ua.tag_id != t.tag_id**? I will update my answer again...

Comment: @Poiz yes it says i don't want select those those tags from tags table which have subscribed by say for an example user_id 14 in user alert table.

Comment: @kirangadhvi sorry i dont have exact DB so i can;t try anymore

Comment: @kirangadhvi data please

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan you can take any dummy data.

Comment: @kirangadhvi it will take much time to manual entry of the data. if you provide data then maybe i'll try